# Using array in different class

Tags: java, arrays

I want to use an value array from one class to another class. In ActivityReceiver, I took an array and pass it into String inkLevel [][].

After that I want to get the specific value,so that I have getInkLevel and return it into array that save the specific value(which is color[]) that I want.

```
 public class ActivityReceiver extends Activity {

   public ArrayList<String[]> arrays ;
   public String[]color = new String [4];
   public  String[][] inkLev ;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

      if (bundle != null) 
      {

          int count = bundle.getInt("com.PrinterStatus.AppLab.ARRAYS_COUNT", 0);
          ArrayList<String[]> arrays = new ArrayList<String[]>(count);
          for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
          {

              arrays.add(bundle.getStringArray("com.PrinterStatus.AppLab.ARRAY_INDEX" + i));
              String[][] inkLev = arrays.toArray(new String[][]{});
          }
      }

      }
    public String[] getInkLevel(String[] lev)
    {
        color[0]= inkLev[0][2];
        color[1]= inkLev[1][2];
        color[2]= inkLev[2][2];
        color[3]= inkLev[3][2];

        return color;

    }
```

In another class. I have enterednumberC variable. And I want to put the specific value,example color[1] into that variable.

```
   ...
   tonerAmountC = (TextView)mSmartView.findViewById(R.id.ImageC);
   tonerAmountC.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) 
   {
     enterednumberC = ??;
     Log.d(SampleExtensionService.LOG_TAG, "Read from file: " + enterednumberC);
     tonerAmountC.setText(enterednumberC);
   }
   });
    mSmartView.addViewToWatch(tonerAmountC);
  ...
```

Do you know what should I add?Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu need to retrieve the array first using. You need an instance of the class to access the array

```
someStringArray = new ActivityReceiver().getInkLever();
enteredNumberC = someStringArray[1];
```